# Define variable template in a class template

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14

Consider this minimal example:

```
template<class X> struct foo;

template<>
struct foo<int>
{
    template<class = void>
    static constexpr int x = 0;
};

template<class T>
constexpr int foo<int>::x<T>;
```

The last two lines are needed because otherwise we will get an undefined reference when the variable `x` is ODR-used.

While gcc (6.2.1) is happy to compile this code, clang (3.9.0) fails on the last line with this cryptic message:

> error: variable template partial specialization does not specialize
>   any template argument; to define the primary template, remove the
>   template argument list

Which one is the correct behavior?

Comment: @Holt http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78121ed2a80f2a59

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last 2 lines of code should be:

```
template<class T>
const int foo<int>::x;
```

or

```
template<class T>
constexpr int foo<int>::x;
```

likes [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UKJeuCYC6rla2BCa)